# How to upload all html, css and javascript at once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created 3 different html, css and javascript files but I am now confuse how can I interlink them and upload as a single file

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the environment you are using and the process in which you upload files. At present there is not enough information to answer this.

Comment: You don't in favor of caching and keeping inline scripting out of the equation. As your pages may change you may carry scripts to other HTML sources and keeping it separated is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're just getting introduced to web development, these might come in handy for finding out how to bring your HTML, JS and CSS files together:

1. (Link JS File) - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp
2. (Link CSS file) - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp
3. https://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 0):

To inter-link different HTML files together, you can just use Hyperlink, Hyperlinking is a feature of HTML to link multiple documents (HTML) files together. It'll show up as a button on your HTML.

Here's an example of how you can implement it. `href="your-path-to-your-html"`

```
<a href="school.html" title="School">Click here to visit school</a>
<a href="inventory.html" title="Inventory">Click here to visit inventory</a>
<a href="battle.html" title="Battle">Click here to visit battle</a>
```

To understand more about hyperlinking, you can read this for better examples: https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_links.asp

Comment: can i upload multiple index.html and link them for new page? Thanks i am. Understanding hope you will help me in my future problems too

Comment: @howisthis yes you can upload multiple html files and link them for a new page, however, you'll need to rename the other pages to something else or at the least place them into different folders and then you place a hyperlink to link the pages together.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your codes to be run by browser you need to include all your sources in one `.html` file. You need to link those files inside this file and there are different requirement of each file extensions to be included.
In order to link CSS file you use `link` element with `src` attribute to indicate the source of your file. Another attribute `rel` defines the relationship between a linked resource and the current document. In here it is stylesheet document and need to get this value.
Sample:    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`

In order to link your JS file, you need to use  element which is used to define a client-side script (JavaScript). You may add it internally or externally. According to your question you need to add it externally. First, add your `script` element and then refer to it using the `src` attribute in the `script` tag.
Sample:    `<script src="myJSFile.js">`

Resources for learning more in these topics:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp
```